# Is it possible to control the radius of the skin modifier with geometry nodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to apply to an object (formed by only vertices) a skin modifier, and then control the radius of the modifier using geometry nodes?
This means that the object would have two modifiers, first the skin and then the geometry node that controls the radius.

Comment: I think this has already been asked before but can't find the question. The current implementation of the skin modifier is convoluted and uses a very specific attribute that's not exposed to geometry nodes. The plan is to change the skin modifier to accept regular attributes down the line ,according to the developer's message on this RCS proposal https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Zqhbbc/?sorting=hot

Comment: i think this is quite "dangerous" because you want to change the first modifier of the same object by the second modifier? i think you could easily produce infinite loops with this...and although i don't know but i doubt that Blender can do this. But maybe i am wrong

Comment: I'd do it the other way around, changing a specific attribute in Geometry Nodes, which is used by the skin modifier afterwards. This makes more sense, as one can control the thickness of the skin modifier using `Ctrl` + `A` in edit mode.

Comment: the way it should work in theory is, you store an attribute in a modifier before the skin modifier, but that isn't possible at the current moment. I need to check about a modifier afterwards; I don't know how the skin modifier works with attributes, if it removes then, then it wouldn't work, but if it keeps them then you might be able to

Comment: doesn't look promising, and for more issues one being that the junctions topology and placement makes it hard to scale them to 0 and still keep a good shape